# get solana transaction-history for a given address - based on date range

Tags: transactions, rust

I want to use Rust or Python to retrieve historical Solana transactions for a given wallet - in a specific date range.

There is the `get_confirmed_signature_for_address2()` which returns signatures for a given address, with an option to get signatures before a given signature.

But how can I find historical transactions using a specific timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBlockTime` will give you the estimated time for a given block

`getBlock` will give the list of signatures in a specific block

`getSignatures` will get you the signatures for an address 1000 at a time, before or after a given signature.

Combine them with a binary search algorithm to find nearby timestamp